How do I replicate an xtabs output using Flextable?
I need to re-create the following output using Flextable since it formats prettier, and specifically Flextable since I will be exporting to Word. Anyone good with Flextable?
Here is my code and output:
attach(warpbreaks)
xtabs(breaks~tension+wool)

      wool
tension   A   B
      L 401 254
      M 216 259
      H 221 169


You can use as_flextable()
library(flextable)
attach(warpbreaks)
xtabs(breaks~tension+wool) |> 
  as_flextable(
    include.row_percent = FALSE,
    include.column_percent = FALSE,
    include.table_percent = FALSE)




Thank you David, you are the best. I see you always answer the questions regarding your package.

when I am online or when there is an answer!
